# Правильний ужиток слів «те» і «то»

Tags: вибір-слова, різниця-між-словами

Я часто чую «те» у спілкуванні українською. Наприклад, «те, що я сказав». Але також мені незвично говорити, наприклад, «що те таке?». Тут чомусь мені здається, що більше підходить «то». Як насправді правильно використовувати ці слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ви маєте рацію: казати «що те таке?» і «то, що я сказав» не слід. Але, боюся, конкретно для цих прикладів пояснення банальне:

- Конструкція «те, що» (приблизний відповідник англ. «that which») є сталою і не допускає заміни «те» на «то». Якби хтось сказав «то, що», я би поправив людину, уточнивши, що це русизм.
- Вираз «що то таке?» також є в кращому випадку сталим, а в гіршому — ще й не зовсім нормативним (більш звично було б — залежно від значення — «що це таке?» або «що ото таке?»). Якби хтось сказав «що те таке?», я би перепитав «що те *що* яке?», бо «те» звучить тут на слово в ролі прикметника.

Робити ж узагальнення, на жаль, важко, бо і слово «те», і слово «то» мають в українській по кілька різних значень із різними особливостями вжитку кожне.